# Change date format with month name to dd/mm/YYYY

Tags: php, date

I have a string with a date in this format: April 16, 2017 23:59, I would like to write a function to change it so that it's in this format: dd/mm/YYYY eg 16/04/2017

I tried to use the date function but couldn't get it to work. Does anyone know how I can do this in PHP?

Comment: echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime('April 16, 2017 23:59'));

Comment: $date = date_create('April 16, 2017 23:59'); print_r(date_format($date, 'd/m/Y H:i:s'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = 'April 16, 2017 23:59';

echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime($date));
```